# Can I create shorthand names for use inside cmd?

Tags: cmd, shortcut

Is it possible to make shortcuts so that I can type "cd desk" instead of "cd desktop" to change directory to the desktop? This would only work if desktop is the only folder or file within the current directory that starts with "desk" but I would really like to do this.

Comment: You should provide some even simple examples that suits to your question.

Comment: Could the *macro* feature of [`doskey`](http://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html) be an option for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't, but you can use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to complete the correct name. Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> multiple time cycles through the matching names existing in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

See `Doskey /?`.

You could do this

```
doskey cddesk=cd "%userprofile%\desktop"
```

Then type `cddesk`.

By putting all your macros in a batch file you can autoload. Of course you could do this with batchfiles too.

From *Technical Reference to the Windows 2000 Registry*, Microsoft, 2000.

**AutoRun**

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

**Data type Range Default value**

REG_SZ  list of commands  There is no default value for this entry.

**Description**

Contains commands which are executed each time you start Cmd.exe.

Also see this batchfile https://pastebin.com/A2qLw8r3 that list special names.

In a command prompt

```
start shell:desktop
```

Or in Start - Run (Winkey + R) just

```
shell:desktop
```