# How to execute a .jar file with a single command on windows?

Tags: java, windows, cmd, jar

I want to be able to execute this code:

```
java -jar myJar.jar arg0 arg1
```

as:

```
program arg0 arg1
```

I'm on **Windows** and was only able to find how to do it on **Linux** (which I don't have and can't understand anyway).

Comment: What do you mean by *single command*? `java` **is** a single command

Comment: @JacobG.I don't want to write "java -jar myJar.jar". I want to write just "program". So basically a single word with no spaces in between.

Comment: May I ask why you want to do that? This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @JacobG. It's for a CLI and I don't want the user to be writing a long command every time he needs to execute a command. For example: "java -jar myJar.jar -help" , I believe is way too long for just a simple help command and I want it to look like "program -help"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54956072/can-i-create-shorthand-names-for-use-inside-cmd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a custom `bash` script that executes your jar.

With `"$@"` you can forward all arguments passed to the bash script to your jar.

```
java -jar <your-jar> "$@"
```

Execute it like that:

`script.bat arg1 arg2 arg3`