# Is it possible to change the directory of a windows console from an app?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, console

My goal is to write an app that lets you quickly assign aliases to long directory paths and change to them.  I wrote an app that manages them in a file in the user's appdata directory, but I can't find a way to change the directory of the shell I run the program in from my app.  My goal is to have it work from git bash, cmd.exe, and powershell.  I want something like this:

```
cd /c/vsts/some-long-project-name-reports
g -a reports
```

Now I have an alias 'reports' for that directory.  What I want to do get to that directory next time I open a console is:

```
g reports
```

I'm using dotnet core, though looking through questions it seems like there isn't a way to do this at all.  With `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(path);` or `Environment.CurrentDirectory = path;` it changes the working directory of the g.exe process, but when it exits the shell goes back to it's working directory when I ran the command.

I've come up with a solution for git bash, I changed my `g` app to output the path instead and have this as `go` in my path:

```
OUTPUT="$(g $1)"
cd $OUTPUT
```

Then I just need to use `.` or `source` to run the script in the current shell:

```
. go reports
```

And batch file `go.bat` doesn't need the `.` or `source` to work:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in ('g %1') do set OUTPUT=%%i
cd %OUTPUT%
```

I guess I'll have to live with typing the extra characters, but is there a similar way to do this with powershell?

Comment: In a command prompt type `doskey /?`. See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54956072/can-i-create-shorthand-names-for-use-inside-cmd

Comment: There's no such thing as "the directory of a windows console" (it's an I/O device with input/screen buffer files that are associated with a window), so I suppose what you want is to change the working directory of a parent process, specifically for the command-line shells that you've listed. There's no general solution for that. I could speculate on hacky workarounds, but you've already found the best solution for CMD, using a batch script. For bash and PowerShell, I suggest that you implement this using a function instead of a script.

Answer (score 1):

Define a *wrapper function* in PowerShell (assuming that `g.exe` *outputs* the target path):

```
function g { Set-Location (g.exe $args) }
```

---

Generally, as [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun) points out in a comment, an executable - which by definition runs in a *child process* - cannot change its *parent* process' working directory.
Therefore, the only solution is to *output* the target directory's path and let the parent process change to it.